# SQL how to seprate 2 words

Tags: sql

INSERT INTO PartyTable 
(Name ,City ,Department ,Age ,Gender ,Transport ,Food ,Drink)
VALUES ('Ido', 'Ramla', 'management', '17', 'M', NULL, NULL, 'Vodka' 'Water');

i need the vodka and water in same box
when it displayed it show VodkaWater
instead Vodka Water

Comment: but your question is so trivial, did you attempted to search?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about software testing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the strings when reading from the DB, you should do it with a select:

```
SELECT Food + Drink as FoodDrink FROM PartyTable;
```

It will return only on column, called FoodDrink, where each row is the concatenation of the Food and Drink columns for each row in PartyTable.

Comment: It really depends on DBMS. In Oracle that would be `SELECT Food || Drink as FoodDrink FROM PartyTable;`

Comment: The point is the semantics. If the syntax is different, anyone can change it.